# Can mono make Solution files (.sln)

Tags: c#, .net, mono

If mono can make .sln files (from cli) How do I do that?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790

Comment: that question is "Is it possible to *build* existing Visual Studio solutions *from* mono", this here "Can mono *make* Solution files (*for* Visual studio)". not exactly duplicate.

Comment: might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151857/does-monodevelop-2-1-support-visual-studio-2010-project-files though.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "make"?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean:

- `make`==`create`, then the [MonoDevelop IDE](http://monodevelop.com/) is able to load and save Visual Studio solutions files.
- `make`==`build`, then the [answer already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790).

Comment: `from cli`. MonoDevelop *is not* a cli.

Answer (score -1):

Right, the answer already exist, and it is [xbuild](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/xbuild/).
Enjoy!